# Execute complex query using Session (coldfusion.air.session class)

Tags: orm, air, coldfusion-9

We are working on a sync application using ColdFusion 9.0.1 ActionScript ORM Library for AIR applications. Since this is application should work smoothly offline as well, there is a list of clients that has to be loaded when a user logs in, hence we are fetching data from all the required tables when application loads (is that the right way?). Now when we get the data from the required tables then based on the user who logs in we have to filter the clients, to filter this the query required is a complex one with joins between 5-6 tables and where clause. What I found that using the Coldfusion.Air.Session class we can only load objects of tables with simple where clause. There is non ORM way to load the data but I don't think that is the right method. Is there any method using this ORM framework to load data using such complex queries.

Thanks,
Gaurav

Comment: Does any one has some inputs on this /

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any CF code to send data back to your application? Have you tried HQL?

In other words you can write standard cfquery and dbtype="hql" 
This will let you do almost anything you can do with a standard cfquery.

I am not directly familiar with the ActionScript ORM Library for AIR.